What does 'Auto' mean in the context of a theme?
I'm trying to implement a light\dark option for my Bootstrap theme. That's working nicely. The example I'm working with also has an Auto option. I'd like to implement that too but I'm not exactly sure what it means. How should I go about determining what to do when a user selects this option. Should I just treat it like another way to select the light theme or is there a place I should be looking for an actual user preference or light level on a phone, maybe? This is for a website if that isn't obvious.

The "Auto" option in switching between light and dark themes usually means selecting the device's settings.
For web sites, you can use media query preferences-color-scheme in CSS to automatically change the theme based on the user's system preferences.
Here is a small example:
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { / * Styles for dark themes */}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) { / * Styles for light theme */}

As for lighting, this is a slightly more complex process and is set mainly through JavaScript using the same API as the device's light sensor.
